# jquery validation rules for radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, jquery-validate

```
    $('#myform').validate({
    // other options & rules
});
```

I am using these rules for validating various fields of myform using there field names. Now I also have a couple of radio buttons to which i need to apply validation on with the rule: "atleast one of the radio buttons need to be selected". Also I need to mention this .Myform is a form for streams and a nested form for stream_details as my association goes like this Stream has_many StreamDetail. And the radio buttons fall under the nested form. The problem here is the name of the radio button i got on inspect element was something weird like "stream[stream_details_attributes][0][show_details][0]". Can't get how to apply validation on this. I though tried to put a class on the buttons and add rules on it. didn't work though.

Comment: You need to show us the relevant HTML. Do all of the radio buttons in one group contain the same `name`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a few ways this can be done.  It's hard to tell by your OP, but maybe #3 is what you'd need...

---

---

**1.**  When the `name` is the *same* on every radio in the group...

```
    <input type="radio" name="radioname" /> <label>Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radioname" /> <label>No</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radioname" /> <label>Maybe</label>
```

Then you can simply declare the `required` rule on this name and one radio out of the group will be required.  (Since it's a `type="radio"` sharing a `name` (same group), only one can be selected in the first place.)

```
$('#myform').validate({
    // other options,
    rules: {
        radioname: { // <- NAME of every radio in the same group
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

---

---

**2.**  When the `name` is *different* on each radio in the group...

```
    <input type="radio" name="foo" class="mygroup" /> <label>Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="bar" class="mygroup" /> <label>No</label>
    <input type="radio" name="foobar" class="mygroup" /> <label>Maybe</label>
```

Then you can use the `require_from_group` rule that is part of [the plugin's `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js).  The first parameter tells it how many from the group are required.

```
$('#myform').validate({
    // other options,
    rules: {
        foo: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup']
        },
        bar: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup']
        },
        foobar: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup']
        }
    }
});
```

---

---

**3.**  When the `name` is *different* on each radio in the group AND you do not know the `name` attribute (*although a `name` on each is still mandatory*).

```
    <input type="radio" name="foo" class="mygroup" /> <label>Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="bar" class="mygroup" /> <label>No</label>
    <input type="radio" name="foobar" class="mygroup" /> <label>Maybe</label>
```

Then you would declare the rules using the `.rules('add')` method.  This method can be attached to ***any*** selector so you would not need to *know* the `name` attributes. (However, even though you're not using the `name` here, the plugin ***mandates*** that every input considered for validation contains a `name`.)

```
$('#myform').validate({
    // other options
});

$('.mygroup').each(function () {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        require_from_group: [1, $(this)]
    });
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/05qm3r4m/**

You can use [the `groups` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#groups) within `.validate()` to combine the error messages into one single message.  Then use [the `errorPlacement` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) to place it precisely within your layout.

**DEMO with combined messages:  http://jsfiddle.net/05qm3r4m/1/**

Comment: I have dynamically created radio button like this

`<input type="radio" value="1" class="new-control-input" name="question_id[1]">`
`<input type="radio" value="0" class="new-control-input" name="question_id[1]">`
.
.
`<input type="radio" value="1" class="new-control-input" name="question_id[10]">`
`<input type="radio" value="0" class="new-control-input" name="question_id[10]">`

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Try it like like

```
<input type="radio" name="radioButtonName" value="1" />First
<input type="radio" name="radioButtonName" value="2" />Second
```

**Rule:**

```
{
    radioButtonName:"required"    
}
```

Comment: Actually I have one form thats built for two objects of same model. i.e. StreamDetails has two types and form is built for each of the two types (Stream accepts_nested_attributes_for stream_details), and hence the same radio button has two names in two different object forms

Answer (score -1):

### You could use this

```
$(".selector").validate({
rules: {
// simple rule, converted to {required:true}
name: "required",
// compound rule
email: {
required: true,
email: true
}
}
});
```

### For More Options you could check jquery validate plugin site

http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Answer (score -1):

Check this:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        input.error 
        {
            border: solid 1px red;  
            color: Red;    
        }
    </style>
     <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#form").validate({
                rules: {
                    accountType: "required"
                },
                messages: {
                    accountType: "You must select an account type"
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form id="form" method="post" action="/">
            <label>Select an Account Type</label>
            <p>
                <input type="radio" name="accountType" value="1" id="accountType_C" /><label for="accountType_C" >Coder</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="radio" name="accountType" value="0" id="accountType_S" /><label for="accountType_S">Surreptitious Ninja</label>
            </p>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```